# CORDA events from within workflows

Tags: corda

Can CORDA workflow publish events? 
When workflow completes, a notification needs to be sent out to external entities who are not part of CORDA network. An example could be to send email notifications to some individuals associated with one of the parties. How can this be accomplished with Corda?

Answer (score 0):

Corda flows are best suited for processing Corda transactions and only transactions due to each flow's asynchronous nature.

Sending notifications as a result of recording a fully signed transaction to the ledger is a common use case and it is best to do this once the vault (database) has been updated. You can easily track changes to the vault by using the `trackBy` or `vaultTrackBy` method: https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html (search "trackBy" for usage).

This allows you to have a callback method on the vault observable where you can send notifications outside of the Corda flow. More good reading on trackBy was covered in this blog: https://lankydanblog.com/2018/10/05/starting-flows-with-trackby/

Reference documentation: https://docs.corda.net/api/kotlin/corda/net.corda.core.node.services/-vault-service/track-by.html

Comment: Thanks Austin. However, it seems CORDA events subscribed to using vaultTrackBy in an RPC client are not durable. If my RPC application which is listening for events using vaultTrackBy is down and if any events are generated, then upon start of RPC application - those events are not delivered.
Is there a way to get those events when RPC application was down.

Comment: Here is an example of how to catch up on events when rpc server was down:

https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#reconnecting-rpc-clients

Thanks Austin for pointing it out

Comment: Good question, noted this question and answer separately: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56821224/retrieving-missed-corda-transactions-from-an-rpc-client-vaulttrackby/56821225#56821225