# Retrieving missed Corda transactions from an RPC client vaultTrackBy

Tags: corda

Corda transactions can be subscribed to using vaultTrackBy from an RPC client but these transactions events can be missed if the RPC connection goes down. RPC disconnects can be a common event so is there a way to retrieve missed transactions when an RPC connection is restored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corda does not assume that the RPC client is durable and assumes that the connection will drop from time to time. Here is one example of how to catch up to events you've missed while the RPC connection was down. https://docs.corda.net/clientrpc.html#reconnecting-rpc-clients